# Serenity Platform Subscription

Tags: serenity-platform

We have a question regarding serenity subscription. Suppose we have already purchased a subscription and have successfully deployed serenity applications to our client. On client perspective, after subscription expires what will happen to those deployed applications? Are our client will still be able to use it?

Thanks

Comment: This question can be posted on startsharp repository. And answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks Victor, how about those StartSharp features that comes in the paid version, will it still work after subscription expires?

Comment: Yes, just you can't get updates.